# Getting a script from a gameobject using a string Unity

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, components

I am working on a simple weapons controller for my FPS game and have come across an issue while trying to make it dynamic. What I want to happen when the player picks up a weapon is for the weapons stats and effects to be set as default. To do this each weapon has a script which is

`weapon.name + "Stats"`

But I'm having issues referencing said script. Right now, this is what my code looks like:

```
string weaponScriptName = weapon.name + "Stats";
weapon.GetComponent<weaponScriptName>().UseWeapon();
```

where `weapon` represents the currently equipped weapon's `gameobject`. Obviously, this doesn't work and various implementations that I've found on the Unity help pages only cause more errors. What can I do to solve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use string if possible ... use e.g. an enum switch to decide for predefined types .. strings is always error prone and slow!

Comment: @derHugo Sorry, I'm quite new to Unity. How would I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) has multiple overloads.

- There is the [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/generics/) version you refer to - the most commonly used one

  ```
  T GetComponent<T>()
  ```

  which you can only use with a compile time constant type parameter such as

  ```
  var renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
  ```
- There is one using a dynamic [`Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.type)

  ```
   Component GetComponent (Type type)
  ```

  like

  ```
   // Just an example, there are many ways of getting a type
   var type = typeof(Renderer);
   var renderer = (Renderer) GetComponent(type);
  ```
- And finally there is one taking a `string`

  ```
  Component GetComponent (string typeName);
  ```

  like

  ```
  // Again just an example, there are many ways of getting type names
  // Especially when dealing with multiple assemblies you might even have to use the AssemblyQualifiedName
  var renderer = (Renderer) GetComponent("Renderer");
  ```

Note that for any of the dynamic versions you either have to **type cast** or if it is enough to have only a generic `Component` reference you can use it of course.

---

However, as said if anyhow possible **don't use `string` versions at all!**

It is always slow and error prone. Rather use e.g. some common base class or [interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface), or use an enum or `Dictionary` to decide what to do for which state.

So I would rather have e.g.

```
public interface IWeapon
{
    void UseWeapon();
}
```

and then every of your different weapons can implement this interface

```
public class WeaponA : MonoBehaviour, IWeapon
{
    public void UseWeapon ()
    {
        Debug.Log("Used Weapon A");
    }
}

public class WeaponB : MonoBehaviour, IWeapon
{
    public void UseWeapon ()
    {
        Debug.Log("Used Weapon B");
    }
}
```

and your code would simply be

```
var weapon = someObject.GetComponent<IWeapon>(). UseWeapon();
```

Or if your weapons all share some common implementation such as pickup etc rather have a common base class

```
public abstract class BaseWeapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Everything that all weapons share as behavior and properties

    // every subclass HAS TO implement and override this method
    public abstract void UseWeapon ();

    // Alternatively if there even is some common behavior
    // subclasses CAN but don't have to override this
    //public virtual void UseWeapon ()
    //{
    //    // Implementation that is the default behavior
    //}
}
```

And then

```
public class WeaponA : BaseWeapon
{
    public override void UseWeapon ()
    {
        Debug.Log("Used Weapon A");

        // If using virtual before then this class IGNORES and fully overwrites the default implementation
    }
}

public class WeaponB : BaseWeapon
{
    public override void UseWeapon ()
    {
        // If using virtual and you WANT the default behavior then add
        //base.UseWeapon();

        Debug.Log("Used Weapon B");       
    }
}
```

and your code would simply be

```
var weapon = someObject.GetComponent<BaseWeapon>(). UseWeapon();
```

Answer (score 1):

If i got it correctly, you want to do something like `GetComponent<"Transform">()` ?
If so, you should do `GetComponent("Transform");` instead

Comment: No, I'm not trying to get the transform component, I'm trying to get a script component from the gameobject 'weapon'

Comment: I was giving an example. sure you can chang the string `"Transform"` with whatever other component name you have !